# Resetting Waitable Timers

Tags: winapi

From MSDN:

> The [CancelWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681985.aspx) function does not change the signaled state of the timer. It stops the timer before it can be set to the signaled state and cancels outstanding APCs. Therefore, threads performing a wait operation on the timer remain waiting until they time out or the timer is reactivated and its state is set to signaled. *If the timer is already in the signaled state, it remains in that state.*

(Emphasis mine)

So: How do I set a manual-reset waitable timer to the non-signalled state, if I can't call CancelWaitableTimer? ResetEvent doesn't work on waitable timers (it fails with ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE).

I don't want to use SetWaitableTimer, because (at this point) I don't know what duration to set it to. I suppose I could set the delay to a large number, but that feels like a bit of a hack to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just call SetWaitableTimer with some very large time which isn't ever going to happen?  And then call it again once you know the real time.

Update: *Hack or not, the docs are pretty clear that a m-r waitable timer "remains in the signalled state until SetWaitableTimer is called".  Seems to me that that's the function you're going to have to use.  You'll just have to have a nice constant called 'RESET_TIMER' which is set to -2^63 or something.*

Comment: I could, but that's a bit of a hack.

Comment: And after `SetWaitableTimer()` call `CancelWaitableTimer()`. It sets the timer to inactive state - so it remains like it wasn't set before (but I didn't verify it).

Answer (score 0):

If you make the waitable timer auto-reset then it will reset automatically as soon as the wait for that timer completes.

However, from MSDN:

> If multiple objects become signaled, the function returns the index of the first handle in the array whose object was signaled.

I originally thought that this means that you can lose a timer signal if an earlier handle in the wait array becomes signaled at the same time as the waitable timer, but I've since read that

> WaitForMultipleObjects() scans the handle array from 0 onwards and returns as soon as it finds a signalled handle. Only that first found handle is reset to the unsignalled state; the others are untouched.

See [Behavior of WaitForMultipleObjects when multiple handles signal at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667319/behavior-of-waitformultipleobjects-when-multiple-handles-signal-at-the-same-time)